# How is the rpath resolved when the application is started via a symlink

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, symlink, ld

I am getting this problem while using `rpath` settings and symlinks on a Linux system. To explain the problem I consider the following setup:

I have an application called `foo` depending on `libbar.so`. The application resides in `$ROOT/pkgs/foo-1.0/bin/` and is symlinked to `$ROOT/bin/`. The library `libbar.so` lives in `$ROOT/lib/`. This gives the following structure:

```
$ROOT/
  bin/
   foo --> $ROOT/pkgs/foo-1.0/bin/foo
  lib/
   libbar.so
  pkgs/
   foo-1.0/
    bin/
     foo
```

The application `foo` now ( to prevent LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings ) a `rpath` set to `$ORIGIN/lib`.

The problem now is `$ORIGIN/lib` is resolved with respect to the resolved symlink and not with respect to the path from where the application is called (`$ROOT/bin`). **How can this be changed?**

A possible solution is to switch to hard links, which works in this case, but I can not ensure the links not point across file system boundaries nor the file systems supports hard links.

Comment: you'd need to set the rpath to $ORIGIN/../../../lib Or you'd need to make `$ROOT/pkgs/foo-1.0/lib` a symlink to `$ROOT/lib/` and use rpath of $ORIGIN/../lib, or make `$ROOT/bin/foo` a shell script that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH. (Just `$ORIGIN/lib` wouldn't work in any of your cases, whether you have a symlink from $ROOT/bin/ or not)

Comment: Symlinking `$ROOT/lib` to `$ROOT/pkgs/foo-1.0/lib` is not an option for me. Because some of my appllication where this problem appear bring their own shared objects in `$ROOT/pkgs/foo-1.0/lib` and they are linked to `$ROOT/lib` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem now is `$ORIGIN/lib` is resolved with respect
>   to the resolved symlink and not with respect to the path from where
>   the application is called (`$ROOT/bin`). **How can
>   this be changed?**

Since the path to the symlink whereby the application was located is not known to the executable wherein the dynamic linking loader `ld.so` resolves *the run-time search path*, the answer to your specific question is: No way.
Apart from that, nos mentioned viable solutions in his comment: *you'd need to set the rpath to $ORIGIN/../../../lib …, or make `$ROOT/bin/foo` a shell script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.*